# Phemex ccxt with python

Tags: python, ccxt

**What is wrong with my code? I want to retrieve my current open positions from my Phemex contract account, but it doesn't output anything, not even indicating that I don't have any open positions.
Here is my code:**

```
import ccxt
import api
import time



exchange = ccxt.phemex({
    'apiKey': api.contract_apiKey,
    'secret': api.contract_secret,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
})


def get_balance():
    params = {"type": "swap", "code": "USDT"}
    response = exchange.fetch_balance(params=params)
    return response


def get_positions():
    params = {"type": "swap", "code": "BTCUSDT"}
    positions = exchange.fetch_positions(params=params)
    return positions


def print_balance():
    balance = get_balance()
    print("Egyenleg:")
    for currency, amount in balance['total'].items():
        print(f"{currency}: {amount}")


def print_positions():
    positions = get_positions()
    if len(positions) > 0:
        print("Aktuális pozíciók:")
        for position in positions:
            if position['symbol'] != 'ETH/USD:USD':
                print(f"Pozíció: {position['symbol']}")
                print(f"  Méret: {position['info']['size']}")
                print(f"  Átlagos nyitási ár: {position['info']['avgEntryPrice']}")
                print(f"  Nyitott oldal: {'Long' if position['info']['side'] == 'buy' else 'Short'}")
                print("---------------")
    else:
        print("Nincsenek aktuális pozíciók.")


while True:
    print_balance()
    print_positions()
    print("------------------------------")
    time.sleep(10)`
```

**Thank you**

Comment: Does the response in get_balance() contain anything? Try printing it.

Comment: The get_balance function is working; it displays my current balance.

Comment: does ```positions = exchange.fetch_positions(params=params)``` contain data?

Comment: Yes, but I receive information about ETH, which in fact doesn't exist.
************Position************
[{'collateral': 0.0,
  'contractSize': 0.005,
  'contracts': 0.0,
  'datetime': None,
  'entryPrice': 0.0,
  'hedged': False,
  'id': None,
...
...
...
'size': '0',
           'symbol': 'ETHUSD',
           'takerFeeRateEr': '-100000000',
           'term': '1',
           'transactTimeNs': '1684828800001568784',
           'usedBalance': '0E-8',
           'usedBalanceEv': '0',
...
...

Comment: So, "it doesn't output anything" isn't true. It appears that the issue isn't with your code, but either your API call or the response.

Comment: I don't know what the problem could be

Answer (score 1):

The current solution of the fetch_positions() method for the Phemex exchange in the CCXT library is not quite the best programmed.

You must first define the symbols for which you want to download open positions and then filter the result where the size of the position is greater than zero.

Attention, if you call the fetch_positions() method without the symbols parameter, the method does not return relevant data.

Tested on CCXT version 3.1.17.

I created a [bug](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/18099) directly in CCXT library git, before they can fix it you can use the solution mentioned above.

**Code example**

```py
class CcxtTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.exchange = ccxt.phemex({
            'apiKey': "",
            'secret': "",
            'enableRateLimit': True,
        })
        
        # only for testing purpose
        #self.exchange.set_sandbox_mode(enabled=True)

    def test_fetch_positions(self):
        # Actually open position 0.01 EHT and 10 DOGE
        symbols = ["BTCUSDT", "ETHUSDT", "DOGEUSDT"]
        positions_raw = self.exchange.fetch_positions(symbols=symbols)

        print("Position raw: {}".format(positions_raw))

        positions = [x for x in positions_raw if float(x["info"]["size"]) > 0]

        print("Positions: {}".format(positions))

        self.assertEqual(positions[0]["info"]["symbol"], "DOGEUSDT")
        self.assertEqual(positions[0]["info"]["size"], "10")

        self.assertEqual(positions[1]["info"]["symbol"], "ETHUSDT")
        self.assertEqual(positions[1]["info"]["size"], "0.01")
```

**Positions raw response**

```json
[
    {
        "info": {
            "userID": "1006534",
            "accountID": "10065340003",
            "symbol": "DOGEUSDT",
            "currency": "USDT",
            "side": "Buy",
            "positionStatus": "Normal",
            "crossMargin": false,
            "leverageRr": "-10",
            "initMarginReqRr": "0.1",
            "maintMarginReqRr": "0.01",
            "riskLimitRv": "200000",
            "size": "10",
            "valueRv": "0.7315",
            "avgEntryPriceRp": "0.07315",
            "avgEntryPrice": "0.07315",
            "posCostRv": "0.07354501",
            "assignedPosBalanceRv": "0.07435818",
            "bankruptCommRv": "0.00000006",
            "bankruptPriceRp": "0.00001",
            "positionMarginRv": "75.640717136268",
            "liquidationPriceRp": "0.00001",
            "deleveragePercentileRr": "0",
            "buyValueToCostRr": "0.10114",
            "sellValueToCostRr": "0.10126",
            "markPriceRp": "0.073068683",
            "estimatedOrdLossRv": "0",
            "usedBalanceRv": "0.07435818",
            "cumClosedPnlRv": "0",
            "cumFundingFeeRv": "0",
            "cumTransactFeeRv": "0.0004389",
            "transactTimeNs": "1685639599370317039",
            "takerFeeRateRr": "-1",
            "makerFeeRateRr": "-1",
            "term": "1",
            "lastTermEndTimeNs": "0",
            "lastFundingTimeNs": "0",
            "curTermRealisedPnlRv": "-0.0004389",
            "execSeq": "1750338145",
            "posSide": "Merged",
            "posMode": "OneWay",
            "buyLeavesValueRv": "0",
            "sellLeavesValueRv": "0"
        },
        "id": null,
        "symbol": "DOGE/USDT:USDT",
        "contracts": 10.0,
        "contractSize": null,
        "unrealizedPnl": null,
        "leverage": -10.0,
        "liquidationPrice": 1e-05,
        "collateral": 75.640717136268,
        "notional": 0.7315,
        "markPrice": 0.073068683,
        "lastPrice": null,
        "entryPrice": 0.07315,
        "timestamp": null,
        "lastUpdateTimestamp": null,
        "initialMargin": 0.07435818,
        "initialMarginPercentage": 0.10165164730006836,
        "maintenanceMargin": 0.007315,
        "maintenanceMarginPercentage": 0.01,
        "marginRatio": 9.670717408485e-05,
        "datetime": null,
        "marginMode": null,
        "side": "long",
        "hedged": false,
        "percentage": null
    },
    {
        "info": {
            "userID": "1006534",
            "accountID": "10065340003",
            "symbol": "BTCUSDT",
            "currency": "USDT",
            "side": "None",
            "positionStatus": "Normal",
            "crossMargin": false,
            "leverageRr": "20",
            "initMarginReqRr": "0.05",
            "maintMarginReqRr": "0.005",
            "riskLimitRv": "2000000",
            "size": "0",
            "valueRv": "0",
            "avgEntryPriceRp": "0",
            "avgEntryPrice": "0",
            "posCostRv": "0",
            "assignedPosBalanceRv": "0",
            "bankruptCommRv": "0",
            "bankruptPriceRp": "0",
            "positionMarginRv": "0",
            "liquidationPriceRp": "0",
            "deleveragePercentileRr": "0",
            "buyValueToCostRr": "0.05117",
            "sellValueToCostRr": "0.05123",
            "markPriceRp": "26963.7",
            "estimatedOrdLossRv": "0",
            "usedBalanceRv": "0",
            "cumClosedPnlRv": "-19.6916",
            "cumFundingFeeRv": "0.856435628732",
            "cumTransactFeeRv": "2.65365589",
            "transactTimeNs": "1685639599370317039",
            "takerFeeRateRr": "-1",
            "makerFeeRateRr": "-1",
            "term": "62",
            "lastTermEndTimeNs": "1682344601428187148",
            "lastFundingTimeNs": "1685635200000000000",
            "curTermRealisedPnlRv": "-0.05177328",
            "execSeq": "1750169286",
            "posSide": "Merged",
            "posMode": "OneWay",
            "buyLeavesValueRv": "0",
            "sellLeavesValueRv": "0"
        },
        "id": null,
        "symbol": "BTC/USDT:USDT",
        "contracts": 0.0,
        "contractSize": null,
        "unrealizedPnl": null,
        "leverage": 20.0,
        "liquidationPrice": 0.0,
        "collateral": 0.0,
        "notional": 0.0,
        "markPrice": 26963.7,
        "lastPrice": null,
        "entryPrice": 0.0,
        "timestamp": null,
        "lastUpdateTimestamp": null,
        "initialMargin": 0.0,
        "initialMarginPercentage": null,
        "maintenanceMargin": 0.0,
        "maintenanceMarginPercentage": 0.005,
        "marginRatio": null,
        "datetime": null,
        "marginMode": null,
        "side": "short",
        "hedged": false,
        "percentage": null
    },
    {
        "info": {
            "userID": "1006534",
            "accountID": "10065340003",
            "symbol": "ETHUSDT",
            "currency": "USDT",
            "side": "Buy",
            "positionStatus": "Normal",
            "crossMargin": false,
            "leverageRr": "20",
            "initMarginReqRr": "0.05",
            "maintMarginReqRr": "0.005",
            "riskLimitRv": "1000000",
            "size": "0.01",
            "valueRv": "18.7125",
            "avgEntryPriceRp": "1871.25",
            "avgEntryPrice": "1871.25",
            "posCostRv": "0.946291125",
            "assignedPosBalanceRv": "0.946291125",
            "bankruptCommRv": "0.010666125",
            "bankruptPriceRp": "1777.69",
            "positionMarginRv": "0.935625",
            "liquidationPriceRp": "1787.05",
            "deleveragePercentileRr": "0",
            "buyValueToCostRr": "0.05117",
            "sellValueToCostRr": "0.05123",
            "markPriceRp": "1871.479970115",
            "estimatedOrdLossRv": "0",
            "usedBalanceRv": "0.946291125",
            "cumClosedPnlRv": "-0.065",
            "cumFundingFeeRv": "0",
            "cumTransactFeeRv": "0.14586126",
            "transactTimeNs": "1685639599375750090",
            "takerFeeRateRr": "-1",
            "makerFeeRateRr": "-1",
            "term": "7",
            "lastTermEndTimeNs": "1681289047875676677",
            "lastFundingTimeNs": "1685635200000000000",
            "curTermRealisedPnlRv": "-0.0112275",
            "execSeq": "1750354137",
            "posSide": "Merged",
            "posMode": "OneWay",
            "buyLeavesValueRv": "0",
            "sellLeavesValueRv": "0"
        },
        "id": null,
        "symbol": "ETH/USDT:USDT",
        "contracts": 0.01,
        "contractSize": null,
        "unrealizedPnl": null,
        "leverage": 20.0,
        "liquidationPrice": 1787.05,
        "collateral": 0.935625,
        "notional": 18.7125,
        "markPrice": 1871.479970115,
        "lastPrice": null,
        "entryPrice": 1871.25,
        "timestamp": null,
        "lastUpdateTimestamp": null,
        "initialMargin": 0.946291125,
        "initialMarginPercentage": 0.05057,
        "maintenanceMargin": 0.0935625,
        "maintenanceMarginPercentage": 0.005,
        "marginRatio": 0.1,
        "datetime": null,
        "marginMode": null,
        "side": "long",
        "hedged": false,
        "percentage": null
    }
]
```

**Positions**

```json
[
    {
        "info": {
            "userID": "1006534",
            "accountID": "10065340003",
            "symbol": "DOGEUSDT",
            "currency": "USDT",
            "side": "Buy",
            "positionStatus": "Normal",
            "crossMargin": false,
            "leverageRr": "-10",
            "initMarginReqRr": "0.1",
            "maintMarginReqRr": "0.01",
            "riskLimitRv": "200000",
            "size": "10",
            "valueRv": "0.7315",
            "avgEntryPriceRp": "0.07315",
            "avgEntryPrice": "0.07315",
            "posCostRv": "0.07354501",
            "assignedPosBalanceRv": "0.07435818",
            "bankruptCommRv": "0.00000006",
            "bankruptPriceRp": "0.00001",
            "positionMarginRv": "75.640717136268",
            "liquidationPriceRp": "0.00001",
            "deleveragePercentileRr": "0",
            "buyValueToCostRr": "0.10114",
            "sellValueToCostRr": "0.10126",
            "markPriceRp": "0.073068683",
            "estimatedOrdLossRv": "0",
            "usedBalanceRv": "0.07435818",
            "cumClosedPnlRv": "0",
            "cumFundingFeeRv": "0",
            "cumTransactFeeRv": "0.0004389",
            "transactTimeNs": "1685639599370317039",
            "takerFeeRateRr": "-1",
            "makerFeeRateRr": "-1",
            "term": "1",
            "lastTermEndTimeNs": "0",
            "lastFundingTimeNs": "0",
            "curTermRealisedPnlRv": "-0.0004389",
            "execSeq": "1750338145",
            "posSide": "Merged",
            "posMode": "OneWay",
            "buyLeavesValueRv": "0",
            "sellLeavesValueRv": "0"
        },
        "id": null,
        "symbol": "DOGE/USDT:USDT",
        "contracts": 10.0,
        "contractSize": null,
        "unrealizedPnl": null,
        "leverage": -10.0,
        "liquidationPrice": 1e-05,
        "collateral": 75.640717136268,
        "notional": 0.7315,
        "markPrice": 0.073068683,
        "lastPrice": null,
        "entryPrice": 0.07315,
        "timestamp": null,
        "lastUpdateTimestamp": null,
        "initialMargin": 0.07435818,
        "initialMarginPercentage": 0.10165164730006836,
        "maintenanceMargin": 0.007315,
        "maintenanceMarginPercentage": 0.01,
        "marginRatio": 9.670717408485e-05,
        "datetime": null,
        "marginMode": null,
        "side": "long",
        "hedged": false,
        "percentage": null
    },
    {
        "info": {
            "userID": "1006534",
            "accountID": "10065340003",
            "symbol": "ETHUSDT",
            "currency": "USDT",
            "side": "Buy",
            "positionStatus": "Normal",
            "crossMargin": false,
            "leverageRr": "20",
            "initMarginReqRr": "0.05",
            "maintMarginReqRr": "0.005",
            "riskLimitRv": "1000000",
            "size": "0.01",
            "valueRv": "18.7125",
            "avgEntryPriceRp": "1871.25",
            "avgEntryPrice": "1871.25",
            "posCostRv": "0.946291125",
            "assignedPosBalanceRv": "0.946291125",
            "bankruptCommRv": "0.010666125",
            "bankruptPriceRp": "1777.69",
            "positionMarginRv": "0.935625",
            "liquidationPriceRp": "1787.05",
            "deleveragePercentileRr": "0",
            "buyValueToCostRr": "0.05117",
            "sellValueToCostRr": "0.05123",
            "markPriceRp": "1871.479970115",
            "estimatedOrdLossRv": "0",
            "usedBalanceRv": "0.946291125",
            "cumClosedPnlRv": "-0.065",
            "cumFundingFeeRv": "0",
            "cumTransactFeeRv": "0.14586126",
            "transactTimeNs": "1685639599375750090",
            "takerFeeRateRr": "-1",
            "makerFeeRateRr": "-1",
            "term": "7",
            "lastTermEndTimeNs": "1681289047875676677",
            "lastFundingTimeNs": "1685635200000000000",
            "curTermRealisedPnlRv": "-0.0112275",
            "execSeq": "1750354137",
            "posSide": "Merged",
            "posMode": "OneWay",
            "buyLeavesValueRv": "0",
            "sellLeavesValueRv": "0"
        },
        "id": null,
        "symbol": "ETH/USDT:USDT",
        "contracts": 0.01,
        "contractSize": null,
        "unrealizedPnl": null,
        "leverage": 20.0,
        "liquidationPrice": 1787.05,
        "collateral": 0.935625,
        "notional": 18.7125,
        "markPrice": 1871.479970115,
        "lastPrice": null,
        "entryPrice": 1871.25,
        "timestamp": null,
        "lastUpdateTimestamp": null,
        "initialMargin": 0.946291125,
        "initialMarginPercentage": 0.05057,
        "maintenanceMargin": 0.0935625,
        "maintenanceMarginPercentage": 0.005,
        "marginRatio": 0.1,
        "datetime": null,
        "marginMode": null,
        "side": "long",
        "hedged": false,
        "percentage": null
    }
]
```